# SMS Sending Function not works in PHP

Tags: php, function, sms, message

I am trying to make sms sending functions in php but it not works from my ends `error = env function` I can use `file_get_contents` but this is not good idea to achieve this. I want to learn through bugs and mistakes. So stackoverflow is best for me as I believe.
Please now let me know how I make this correct.
Where I am doing mistake please correct me.
Thank you very much.

```
function sendMessage($route, $sender, $mobile, $message) {
    $message = urlencode($message);

    $url = sprintf("https://www.sms4india.com/send_sms?api_token=%s&route=%s&senderid=%s&number=%s&message=%s",
    env('MY_API_HERE'), $route, $sender, $mobile, $message);

    return $output;
}

sendMessage('4', 'WHTSAP', 'MOBILE_NO', 'HELLO WORLD');
```

Comment: It looks like you just want to call a foreign URL from your PHP script. See here for a starting point how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999323/how-to-access-restful-api-via-php

Comment: It was not helpful I already tour of this thread.

Comment: If you want a more specific help your question needs to be more specific. What is the error you get? Why the solution in the links mentioned above is not an option for you?

Comment: I am not seeing any error but this is not working..